# mysql update table if record not in temp table

Tags: mysql, csv, sql-update, inner-join

Alright, I have multiple MySQL statements that lead into an issue I'm having updating a particular table.  First let me show you my code, then I'll explain what I'm trying to do:

```
/*STEP 1 - create a temporary table to temporarily store the loaded csv*/
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temptable1` LIKE `first60dayactivity`;

/*STEP 2. load the csv into the previously created temporary table*/
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/me/Downloads/some.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE `{temptable}`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
SET CUSTID = 1030,
    CREATED = NOW(),
    isactive = 1;

/*STEP 3. update first60dayactivity table changing isactive for records that are not in the temptable*/
UPDATE `first60dayactivity` fa 
    INNER JOIN `temptable1` temp 
        ON  temp.`mid` = fa.`mid`
        AND temp.`primarypartnername` = fa.`primarypartnername`
        AND temp.`market` = fa.`market`
        AND temp.`agedays` = fa.`agedays`
        AND temp.`opendate` = fa.`opendate`
        AND temp.`CUSTID` = fa.`CUSTID`
SET fa.isactive = IF( temp.`mid` IS NULL, 0, 1 );

/*STEP 4. insert the temp table records into the real table*/
.....blah blah blah.....
```

Ok, first create a temporary table so that we have a table to hold the imported .csv data.  Next, import the .csv data into the temporary table (all this works perfectly so far).

Here is where I run into an issue.  I'm wanting to update the `isactive` column of each record of the `first60dayactivity` table to `0` if the record is NOT found in `temptable1` (after my import).  Ultimately, I'm gathering a .csv, the .csv has the new live data that should be considered "active" and I need to set the old data to `inactive`.  So, the update does an INNER JOIN to match on several column to see if the record is found in the `temptable1`, if it isn't then set the activity to `0`, if it is found in `temptable1` then ensure the activity status is `1`.

The problem here is that all records in `first60dayactivity` are retaining the `1` property to indicate it is active.  Nothing is getting updated to `0` even though I have proof new records exist within `temptable1`...  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

temp.`mid` can never be `NULL` because you use this column in your join condition and you use an `INNER JOIN`.

Your join (without the insert) should return the matching rows. Using a `LEFT JOIN` for the update should do what I suppose you want to do.

Comment: Was the double negative ("can't never be NULL") on purpose? I think not :)

Comment: Thanks, you're right of course. That was a mistake. I've edited my answer.

Comment: looks like you have solved my problem, I knew another set of eyes looking at this would help! Thanks greatly.